# nav-justify behavior in BS4

Tags: html

In BooStrap 3, when we use the nav-justify with navs, as we shrink the page, they become stacked but in BS4, the behavior is different

I tried googling and found nothing so far.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills  nav-justified" >
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So in BS4, the nav-justfied doesn't resize navs as the screen gets smaller. Any workarounds ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference in behaviors is that Bootstrap used `float` to order and align a lot of content in Bootstrap 3, while Bootstrap 4 uses `flexbox`.

In fact, you don't even need to use the `nav-justified` class if you only want to collapse items on smaller screens. In Bootstrap 4, this is the purpose of the `nav-justified` class:

> For equal-width elements, use .nav-justified. All horizontal space will be occupied by nav links, but unlike the .nav-fill above, every nav item will be the same width.

Therefore, you will need to introduce a little flexbox CSS to get what you want. For example, you can make your `nav-justified` list use `flex-direction: row` by default and `flex-direction: column` under a certain breakpoint.

See the following example for an illustration of this: all screens under 768px wide will show the menu vertically and all screens over 768px wide will show the menu horizontally.

```css
/* Set the default direction of your nav */
.nav-justified {
   flex-direction: row;
}

/* For screens under 768px width, change the direction of the nav */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
   .nav-justified {
      flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- The container div is simply to make the example have nicer spacing -->
<div class="container my-4">

   <ul class="nav nav-pills  nav-justified">
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
   </ul>

</div>
```